# Expected time of visits to a transient state in a Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose that $\left\{X_{n}\right\}$ is a Markov chain and $y$ is a transient state. So we know the following:

1) $V(y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{\left\{y\right\}}(X_{k})$, the # of times that we arrive to $y$.

2) $\mathbb{P}(V(y)<\infty)=1$, because the state is transient.

3) $\mathbb{P}_{y}\big[T_{y}< \infty \big]<1$,the probability to start from y and visit again $y$ is less than $1$. Where $T_{y}=\inf\left\{k>0:X_{k}=y\right\}$ is a stopping time.

and we have to show that $\mathbb{E}_{x}\big[V(y)\big]=\mathbb{P}_{x}\big[T_{y}<\infty\big]\mathbb{E}_{y}\big[V(y)\big]$.

I tried to start with the calculation of $\mathbb{E}_{x}\big[V(y)\big]$ but I couldn't take the result.

$$
\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[V(y)\right]=\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{\left\{y\right\}}(X_{k})\right]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[\mathbb{1}_{\left\{y\right\}}(X_{k})\right]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=y|X_{0}=x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\rho^{k}(x,y)
$$

But I can't see how this helps to take the $\mathbb{P}_{x}\big[T_{y}<\infty\big]\mathbb{E}_{y}\big[V(y)\big]$.

Any help or idea would be really helpful.

Comment: If $x=y$ then $$\mathbb{E}_{y}\big[V(y)\big]=\mathbb{P}_{y}\big[T_{y}<\infty\big]\mathbb{E}_{y}\big[V(y)\big] < \mathbb{E}_{y}\big[V(y)\big] $$ since $y$ is transient

Comment: @user365239 But how does this help us to prove that $\mathbb{E}_{x}\big[V(y)\big]=\mathbb{P}_{x}\big[T_{y}<\infty\big]\mathbb{E}_{y}\big[V(y)\big]$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**: Suppose $x \neq y$.
Define $\rho_{xy} := \mathbb{P}_x(T_y < \infty)$, and let $T_y^k$ be the $k$-th return time to $y$.

---

**Lemma**: $\mathbb{P}_x(T_y^k<\infty) = \rho_{xy} \cdot \rho_{yy}^{k-1}$ for all $k \ge 1$ and $x,y \in S$. Prove this with induction, use Strong Markov Property.

---

**Your Problem**: Note that $\mathbb{E}_y[V(y)] = \frac{1}{1-\rho_{yy}}$, since $V(y)$ is geometric with success probability $\rho_{yy}$ conditional upon $X_0 = y$.

Now we need an expression for $\mathbb{E}_x[V(y)]$.

$$
\mathbb{E}_x(V(y)) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}_x(V(y) \ge k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}_x(T_y^k < \infty)
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \rho_{xy} \rho_{yy}^{k-1} = \frac{ \rho_{xy}}{1-\rho_{yy}}
$$

---

My initial comment was to show that the result is obviously  not true for $y=x$.